# StaggeredGridView layout inflation issue

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am using `StaggeredGridView` currently in the project I am working on. But what is happening is the *GridView* layout is not getting inflated in a correct way. when my layout is loaded the *GridView* is rendering with let's say 4 column in my tablet(10" Sony Xperia Z) in landscape mode, but sometime somewhere at any random row number the items are not rendering sequentially but at any random position with uneven void space like the following image:

[image: staggere_img1]

The same type of situation arises when the tablet is in the portrait mode. but surprisingly when the orientation changes then this issue is getting resolved automatically. It's kind of weird problem I am facing right now. I've gone through some research but with no luck.

I've also tried [This StaggeredGridView](https://github.com/bulletnoid/StaggeredGridView), but the same issue.

Can anyone please help me out there? Thanks in advance.

FYI I am using *Viewholder* pattern in my *Gridview Adapter*.

**PS:**

Is the fix **[Fixed whitespace](https://github.com/marcosalis/StaggeredGridView/commit/8b7e62dd8c5731c44f8fc6464dc26433927c326e)** related to my concern? I've tried it but no improvement.

Comment: is it getting shown in some devices or all devices.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in StaggeredGridView during loading images via picasso from network.

When you use:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(getItem(position)).into(holder.imageView);
```

in your adapter, picasso reserve one grid for your image and SGV make rendering for the content. Then image is loaded at last and SGV makes rendering one more time and images change their position in SGV.

Solution: I check size of the image needed for rendering (I my situation I read it from json) in order to reserve demanding space for the image at the beginning. Please take a look in example:

```
public class StaggeredAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Context mContext;

public StaggeredAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                        String[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.row_staggered_demo, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    // Calculate size of the element.
    int height = (position % 3 == 0) ? 600 : (1200 / (position % 3));
    convertView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height));

    Picasso.with(mContext).load(getItem(position)).into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: Very nice library for downloading and caching images. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: problem is still not there

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: when scroll StaggeredGridView up to down and after down to up then grid view not show properly mean if num column more than 1 and image insert more than not show properly

Comment: I don't understand how you calculate the size of the element ? Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the item layout. Does it contain image? When items are inflated, they may have different size. So the layouting process is computed using different item size. Try to use stub images which are used before image loading.

Comment: Yes. It contains images, and i am using picasso for asynchronous image loading with stub image.